# Extending SubmitType for a mapped form use

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Trying to extend the [`SubmitType`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/submit.html):

```php
class ValidateType extends AbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'label' => 'Valider',
            'mapped' => false,
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'btn-lg btn-success btn-block',
            ),
        ));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return SubmitType::class;
    }
}
```

to use into a mapped form

```php
class SecurityFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            // ...
            ->add('validate', ValidateType::class, array('mapped' => false))
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Item::class
        ));
    }
}
```

tells me

> Neither the property "validate" nor one of the methods "getValidate()", "validate()", "isValidate()", "hasValidate()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "AppBundle\Entity\Item".

Am I doing something wrong ?
Is there a way to extend `SubmitType` ?

Comment: Have you define your custom field type as a service ?

Comment: No, why should I ? I am not trying to do an [extension](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_form_type_extension.html), simply a custom form type

Comment: Indeed you are right

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `mapped` property for this case. Instead, use interface `SubmitButtonTypeInterface`

**ValidateType:**

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

class ValidateType extends AbstractType  implements SubmitButtonTypeInterface
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'label'  => 'Valider',
            'attr'   => [
                'class' => 'btn-lg btn-success btn-block',
            ],
        ]);
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return SubmitType::class;
    }
}
```

**SecurityFormType:**

```
$builder
    // ...
    ->add('validate', ValidateType::class)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let your form type class implement the [SubmitButtonTypeInterface](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.0/src/Symfony/Component/Form/SubmitButtonTypeInterface.php) so that the [SubmitButtonBuilder](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.0/src/Symfony/Component/Form/SubmitButtonBuilder.php) is used instead of the regular [FormBuilder](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.0/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilder.php).